# How to get my actual data from ContentNote API in Salesforce using SOQL?

Tags: soql, rest-api, python

My Notes has Title-Task2 and Content is **Talk to customers**

When I run following query:

`SELECT Title,Content FROM ContentNote`

Output is:

```
('Title', 'Task2'),
('Content','/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentNote/0692x000000WFDKAA4/Content')])]
```

how to get my actual content from this?

Comment: What API are you using? It's not immediately obvious from your tags and question exactly how you're querying this data to begin with.

Comment: querySOL = "SELECT Id,Title,Content FROM ContentNote"   notesaccount = sf.query(querySOL)
print(notesaccount)  After this Ouput is as shown in this question how to get data from it

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: I am using Python and with it simple_salesforce Library

Comment: Please use the [edit] function to add this Python code and background to your question. This helps ensure that the rest of the community can benefit from understanding your experience.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API doesn't directly return the contents of the "blob" (**B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject). Instead, you need to retrieve it separately using the URL provided. Looking at the docs, it looks like you should be able to:

```
for record in notesaccount.records:
    sf.restful(notesaccount.Content)
```

In order to retrieve the contents of each note. It's also possible to do this in bulk, but would require writing significantly more code to process the records, and my Python is woefully out of date.

Comment: Can you provide me the link for this Doc and Thanks for help I am very close to what I wanted to get

Comment: @SamadKhan [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a text preview:

```
SELECT Title,TextPreview FROM ContentNote
```